# How to implement newsletter in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, email, mailchimp, newsletter

I try to find in Google. Most of it using mailchimp. Any example or point can be share?

In my assumption. To implement a newsletter it should be batch process to prevent high traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Below url have all the info for how to create a newsletter using codeigniter and jquery

http://blog.3dmick.com/2012/06/newsletter-subscription-in-codeigniter-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a newsletter simply using MailChimp .. you don't even need to do programming!  Since Mailchimp does all the "sending" work, you don't even need to worry about "batch processes or any other local programming considerations".

(If I have not understood your question, please clarify.